# Can you send .json files to an EC2 with scp?

Tags: json, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, permissions

I am currently trying to move a .json file to my EC2 with scp. When I run:

`sudo scp -i key.pem file.json ec2-user@public-ip:/filepath`

in the command line, it returns:

`scp: /file.json: Permission denied`

file.json already has full permissions. Does have something to do with .json file itself or perhaps that scp sends a .json message to the EC2?

Comment: Just an FYI, I do not own the EC2, but I should have full posting access, I can ssh into it just fine. The same error occurs when I try to scp .txt files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can but you need to make sure that your scp user has write permission to the path on the ec2 server. It is quite safe to  you use the home directory of the user as for example ec2-user will surely have the access to its home directory. So as per your command, you can try to use the /home/ec2-user as the destination.

```
sudo scp -i key.pem file.json ec2-user@public-ip:/home/ec2-user
```

You can always move the file around once it is on the box using ssh session.

Comment: Case closed! I think it was trying to place the file into the root directory. Thanks